# CSS selection not working around images

Tags: html, css, selection

I'm trying to change the selection colour on my website but it seems to be causing a problem when selecting around images. Essentially the white space around the images comes out in the default blue whereas everything else comes out in the correct yellow colour.

This is the HTML:

```
<h2>Achievements</h2>
<img src="img/atlassian.png" />
<p>The most reputable and successful start-up in Australian history. Led the design for Confluence over 4 years.</p>
```

This is the CSS:

```
::selection {
background: #fade70; /* Safari & Chrome */
color: #333;
}
::-moz-selection {
background: #fade70; /* Firefox */
color: #333;
}
```

Any idea how I could fix this? Really appreciate your help!

(I tried uploading an image but I didn't have the reputation points, sorry!)

Comment: The selection pseudo-selector has very poor support across browsers, don't expect it to work consistently.

Comment: "Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule using ::selection in its selector: color, background, background-color and text-shadow. Note that, in particular, background-image is ignored, like any other property." *source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection*

Comment: @Mike Koch: But the OP isn't using any disallowed properties...

Comment: Yes, I just realized that actually. But it still isn't a well-supported selector

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's because `img` is not a block element.
You can either enclose it in a `div`

```
<div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=3" />
</div>
```

or style the `img` with `display:block`, something like this.

```
<img class="block" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=3" />

.block {
    display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want it to be an inline element, you don't need a div or styling for the selection colour to be correct. For example,

```
<p>This text is before the image <img src="" /> and this text is after it.</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work if you have text above and/or below the image: http://jsfiddle.net/r4LaY/1/

Comment: By keeping the `img` outside of a block element, you are treating it as one, but you aren't wrapping it in a block.

Comment: Thanks so much! Wrapping it in a `div` worked perfectly. The `display: block` suggestion worked as well but changed my padding so I went with the `div`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The `::selection` pseudo class was drafted for CSS Selectors Level 3 but removed before it reached the Recommendation status. It's not really supposed to be relied on as a fully implemented standard.

Comment: Pseudo-element, not pseudo-class. Hence the double colons.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, was already aware but I appreciate you letting me know.